# C# Rest API Post

Tags: c#, rest

I am trying to get a REST API to feed into https://www.scheduleit.com/faq/10640/is-there-a-rest-api-or-webhooks

I have the get working, put the post I always get

"{"status": "error", "status_code": "404", "message": "Not Found - Invalid End Point for Method POST"}"

Code is

```
            var client = new RestClient("https://www.scheduleit.com/api/");
            var request = new RestRequest(this.TokenEndPoint, Method.POST);
            //client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(userName, password);

            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");


            request.AddParameter("title", "Title Test");
            request.AddParameter("owner", "813");
            request.AddParameter("date_start", "2022-12-05");
            request.AddParameter("date_end", "2022-12-06");


            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Any suggestions

Have tried various ways of coding

Comment: what is the value of `this.TokenEndPoint` ?

Comment: This was  me trying, have now removed this so code is

Comment: var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

Answer (score 1):

The endpoint you specified doesn't exist. You need to include the resource target;

- `/api/groups`
- `/api/resources`
- `/api/events`
- `/api/labels`
- `/api/reports`

You also need to pass arguments in a JSON Body, not as query parameters.

This is how it should look;

```
public class RequestBody {

  [JsonPropertyName("title")]
  public string Title { get; set; }

  [JsonPropertyName("owner")]
  public string Owner { get; set; }

  [JsonPropertyName("date_start")]
  public DateTime DateStart { get; set; }

  [JsonPropertyName("date_end")]
  public DateTime DateEnd { get; set; }

}
```

```
var body = new RequestBody {
  Title = "Title Test",
  Owner = "813",
  DateStart = Date.Now(),
  DateEnd = Date.Now()
};

var client = new RestClient("https://www.scheduleit.com/api/events");

var request = new RestRequest().AddJsonBody(body);

var response = await client.PostAsync(request, CancellationToken.None);
```